# Selenium coding

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

i am new to selenium and i have created a java project with different classes (each class for every page of my application). The project has only 1 main method and the class having main method is inherited by all other classes.
So, is it correct to code in this way that the class having main is inherited by all other classes? 
Or is there some other better way to code?
Another question is, 
The main method has the chrome driver initiation in it as well in addition to objects of all classes used to call the methods of different classes.
Should main contain only objects for all classes? or is there a way to initiate chrome in some other way.
Sample of my code below (main class and login class):

```
    public class Main {
static WebDriver driver;
static Logger logger;
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    logger=Logger.getLogger("Log4jdemo");
    PropertyConfigurator.configure("Log4j.property.txt");
    String exePath = "F:\\selenium\\Chrome Driver\\New Folder\\chromedriver.exe";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", exePath);
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.gmail.com");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    logger.info("Browser launched");
    FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver);
    wait.withTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    wait.pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("ei-login-Username")));
    Login l1 = new Login();
    l1.login();
    A name= new A();
    name.InitiateJourney();
    B IO = new B();
    IO.Help();
    Agreeterms a = new Agreeterms();
    a.Agreeterm();
    AmendDetails ad = new AmendDetails();
    ad.Amend();
    AmendBank ab = new AmendBank();
    ab.amendbankdetails();
}
```

}

```
    public class Login extends Main{    
public void login() throws IOException{
File src = new File("F:\\selenium\\AutomationData.xlsx");
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(src);
XSSFWorkbook wbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fin);
XSSFSheet sheet = wbook.getSheetAt(0);
WebElement username =driver.findElement(By.id("ei-login-Username"));
username.sendKeys("12365478");
WebElement next =driver.findElement(By.id("btnSubmit"));
next.click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(6, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
WebElement pin =driver.findElement(By.id("ei-login-Pin"));
pin.sendKeys("971997");
WebElement login =driver.findElement(By.id("btnPinSubmit"));
login.click();

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html) or [JUnit](http://junit.org/junit4/) frameworks, Main method is not Mandatory for selenium. You can write your own classes and methods. Can call them by Annotations.